# Can't stablish a websocket connection

Tags: angularjs, websocket, vps

I am experiencing troubles with websockets... I was told that to use websockets my hosting service plan should have a feature called "VPS"... So I upgrade to that plan and, when using angular, I saw this message on the log console of firefox...

Firefox no puede establecer una conexión con el servidor en ws://cholordoweb.com:1234/test/.

or

Firefox couldn't stablish a connection to ws

I know there are similar questions but well... I give more details... Thankx !.

My firefox version is 41.0...

```
<html ng-app="CholoApp">
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.1.3.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ng-websocket.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var CholoApp = angular.module("CholoApp",['ngWebsocket']);
        CholoApp.controller("CholoController",function($scope,$websocket){
                var ws = $websocket.$new('ws://cholordoweb.com:1234/test/');
                ws.$on('cholordo', function (message) { // it listents for 'incoming event'
                    alert("Mensaje: " + message);
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CholoController">
</body>
```

And the other is:

```
<html ng-app="CholoApp">
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.1.3.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ng-websocket.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var CholoApp = angular.module("CholoApp",['ngWebsocket']);
        CholoApp.controller("CholoController",function($scope,$websocket){
                var ws = $websocket.$new('ws://cholordoweb.com:1234/test/');

                    ws.$emit('cholordo', 'Cholo WebSocket Is Working !.'); // it sends the event 'hello' with data 'world'

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CholoController">
</body>
```

What could be happening ?.How could I solve it ?. Is there any detail I should put... Thankx

Comment: Does it work with Chrome? Have you tried using wss:\\?

Comment: Vrortola. Thanks for answering... I'll be checking that as soon as posible... Thankx again...

Comment: vtortola: I've tried and I got the same error...  Dunno what's happening... :(

Comment: Is your Websockets server accessible? Maybe your port 1234 is blocked.